# how to adjust the length of angular material md-input

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-material2

how do i adjust the length of the md-input component? the size/width attribute doesn't seem to work. 
in the below example i'm trying to make floor-unit the same length with block number

```
<md-list-item>
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="customer.custEmail" name="custEmail" type="text" placeholder="Email address"></md-input>
</md-list-item>
<md-list-item>
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="customer.custDisplayName" name="custDisplayName" type="text" placeholder="Display Name"></md-input>
</md-list-item>
<md-list-item>
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="customer.addressPostal" name="addressPostal" type="number" placeholder="Postal Code"></md-input>
</md-list-item>
<md-list-item>
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="customer.addressBlk" name="addressBlk" type="number" placeholder="Block No."></md-input>
</md-list-item>
<md-list-item>
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="customer.addressStreet" name="addressStreet" type="number" placeholder="Street"></md-input>
</md-list-item>
<md-list-item>
   <md-input [(ngModel)]="customer.addressFloor" name="addressFloor" type="number" placeholder="Floor" size="4"></md-input> - 
   <md-input [(ngModel)]="customer.addressUnit" name="addressUnit" type="number" placeholder="Unit" size="4"></md-input>
</md-list-item>

</md-list>
```

Comment: uh.. basically the input field being displayed

Answer (score 1):

I am also struggling with styling ng2 material design elements, but I found a way how to overcome this one. Just add class to `md-list-element` and style this class. Just like that:

```
<md-list-item class="same-width">
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="customer.custEmail" name="custEmail" type="text" placeholder="Email address"></md-input>
</md-list-item>
<md-list-item class="same-width">
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="customer.custDisplayName" name="custDisplayName" type="text" placeholder="Display Name"></md-input>
</md-list-item>
```

in css

```
.same-width {
  width: 300px;
}
```

Other option is to modify `md-list-item` element via `material-customization`.

Comment: yeah i know about this, but using pixels is bad when you need to support multiple screensizes.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Angular Material 2 but the "size" attribute seems to work for me

```
  <md-list-item>
     <md-input-container>
         <label>Inputfield</label>
         <input type="text" ng-model="color" size="10">
     </md-input-container>
  </md-list-item>
```